# Speed to power conversion

Tags: power, speed, unit-conversion, fan

[Here](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/191174/files/DATE2014-10.3_1.PDF) it is stated that there is a cubic relationship between fan speed and power consumption (Pfan ∝ FanSpeed^3). I have the fan speed (m/s), but I need to convert it into power (W). How can I compute Pfan from FanSpeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, you cannot. First, a fan speed value in m/s is meaningless. Presumably you are talking either about the speed of the fan blades, probably at their tips, or you are talking about the air velocity produced by the operation of the fan. In the first case, you have left out the diameter of the blades and their aerodynamic efficiency. In the second case, you are missing the volume of air being moved. EDIT In both cases you are ignoring the question of the back pressure on the moving air. A given flow velocity requires more power if it has to overcome a greater back pressure.  Think of the difference between blowing air freely and trying to force it through a filter at the same speed.END EDIT

More fundamentally, you have misread the article. It does not state that power is *equal* to the cube of fan speed, it states that power is *proportional* to the cube of fan speed. In other words, if you want a given fan to spin twice as fast, you must supply 8 times as much power to the fan. This follows simply from the observation that, for a given (more or less ideal) fan, if you double the speed you double the amount of air being moved through the fan, which means that the air stream velocity is doubled. So the kinetic energy of a given volume of air being moved is quadrupled (mv^2/2), and the total volume is doubled, and 4 times 2 is 8.

None of this in any way allows you to derive power solely from fan speed. A big fan moving a lot of air at the same velocity as a small fan will require more power to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, if for example, I have a 25% reduction in air velocity throughout the system, how can I calculate the percent of power reduction?

Comment: In principle, a 25% flow rate reduction is a 25% fan speed reduction. So the new power is .75 x .75 x .75. Depending on details of how the fan is ducted and exactly where the air speed is being measured, this won't be exactly correct, but it should be a useful starting point.